# rhino modules for shiny app - my app does not work

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinymodules

I'm trying to learn the rhino modules to develop R shiny apps but got stuck with this simple app:

app/view/page1.R

```
box::use(
    shiny[moduleServer, textOutput, renderText, NS, div],
    shiny.fluent[TextField.shinyInput, Stack]
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    Stack(TextField.shinyInput(ns("page1input"), value = "default value"),
          textOutput(ns('page1print'))
          )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        output$page1print <- renderText(sprintf("Input from above: %s", input$page1input))
    })
}
```

main.R

```
box::use(
  shiny[div, moduleServer, NS, renderUI, tags, uiOutput, renderText],
  shiny.fluent[fluentPage]
)

box::use(
  app/view/page1
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluentPage(
    page1$ui('p1')
  )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    page1$server('p1')
  })
}
```

I expect the app to print the user's input but it doesn't. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please remove the rhino tag, as this question doesn't seem to be about what the 'rhino' is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add namespacing to your call to `page1$ui`

```r
# main.R

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluentPage(
    page1$ui(ns('p1')) # <- fixed here
  )
}
```

Now `main$server` is able to read inputs from `page1$ui`. Don't worry, everyone makes this mistake several times ;).

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: all right, would you mark this as answered?